# Neo4j embedded database, shutdown, start

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

In my Neo4j + Spring Neo4j Data + Spring Boot application I have a following configuration

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {

        // @formatter:off
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(environment.getProperty(NEO4J_EMBEDDED_DATABASE_PATH_PROPERTY))
                //.setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.pagecache_memory, "2g")
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_keys_indexable, "name,description")
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_auto_indexing, "true")
                .newGraphDatabase();
        // @formatter:on

        return graphDb;
    }
```

I need to (1)shutdown this db, (2)delete database files on disk and then (3)start this database again.

I know how to perform steps #1 and #2 but how to start and initialize the database again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete database files on disk, your DB is gone ...
You can try to recreate a new, empty one, repeating your init code, but it is probably not the task you intent to do ???